# How to protect here maps app_id and app_code

Tags: here-api

I am using the paid version of here maps JavaScript api. I couldn't find anywhere to restrict the API calls from a specific domain.

As per the JavaScript api documentation, I have to use the 'app_id' and 'app_code' to initialise the here maps. But if I do that, anyone can see the 'app_id' and 'app_code' and use these in their website.

So, will I get billed for all these calls made from a different website ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not available as of now. I know there is a plan to add this feature, but there is no solid ETA.

For the time being, you could implement a proxy that would append the key to the HERE API request before being sent to HERE servers. Although it's a brutal hack.